# calculate the component of a tensor-like quantity using xCoba,and how to use ContactBasis ,TraceBasisDummy

Tags: xact

I am trying to do perturbation, it involved terms like this:

$\partial_{l}(g^{lp} g^{kq} h_{pq}) (\partial_{i}g_{jk})
$

I want to obtain the simplified result of the components {i,j}
all other indices like p,q,l,k all traced, contracted.
the code:

```
ClearAll["Global`*"];
Quiet@Block[{Print},
  << xAct`xTensor`;
  << xAct`xTras`;
  << xAct`xCoba`;
  ]
$PrePrint = ScreenDollarIndices;
  DefManifold[M, 4, {i, j, k, l, m, p, q}];
  DefMetric[-1, g[-i, -j], CD, PrintAs -> "g"];
DefChart[sc, M, {0, 1, 2, 3}, {t[], r[], \[Theta][], \[Phi][]}];
DefConstantSymbol[c];
MatrixForm[
  Matrixsc = 
   DiagonalMatrix[   {-c^2, 1, r[]^2, 
     r[]^2 *(Sin[\[Theta][]])^2}     ]];
MatrixForm@MetricInBasis[g, -sc, Matrixsc]
g = CTensor[Matrixsc, {-sc, -sc}];
DefTensor[h[-i, -j], M, Symmetric[{-i, -j}]];
expr= (PDsc[-l][g[l, p] g[k, m] h[-m, -p]]* PDsc[-i][g[-j, -k]] );
mat = Table[TraceBasisDummy[ ContractBasis[ 
     TraceBasisDummy[
      ToBasis[sc][   
       ReplaceIndex[  
        expr, {-i -> {ii, -sc}, -j -> {jj, -sc}   }] ], sc]
     ]]
      , {ii, 0, 3}, {jj, 0, 3}];
```

it doesn't work, probably the problem happens in the command `expr= (PDsc[-l][g[l, p] g[k, m] h[-m, -p]]*  , how to correct it? PDsc[-i][g[-j, -k]] );`
if I put the explict expr into the Table, i.e. `Table[..[ReplaceIndex[(PDsc[-l][g[l, p] g[k, m] h[-m, -p]]*PDsc[-i][g[-j, -k]] ),...]]]`
it yields the desired result,
also, I don't understand TraceBasisDummy and ContractBasis, does their order matters, can Simplification also fits this?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica SE. To get started:1) take [the introductory tour now](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour),2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up [by clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge,3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking checkmark sign](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work),4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Comment: Not sure if you are interested in approaches that do not invoke packages, but there are some replies that deal with metrics and tensor quantities like these on this site. If you want, I can leave some links as a comment